# ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "^F" While try to update table with psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

:) Hi everyone. I use python 2.7 and psycopg2 module to work with Postgres. Sometime when I try to  update one of tables (`record_partitioned` table) in database I get weird exceptions. I use this code to do update.

```
sentiment_query = [int(i) for i in result['result']]
record_query = [int(x[1]) for x in items]
global_cursor.execute("UPDATE record_partitioned SET sentiment = DT.sentiment FROM "
                      "(SELECT UNNEST(%s) AS record_id, "
                      "UNNEST(%s) AS sentiment) AS DT "
                      "WHERE record_partitioned.record_id = DT.record_id",
                      (record_query, sentiment_query))
```

Two `sentiment_query` and `record_query` have same length.
Here is Exceptions:

```
[2022-01-04 11:54:43+0000]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_fetcher.py", line 1428, in worker_sentiment
    (record_query, sentiment_query))
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "^F"
LINE 1: ...ment) AS DT WHERE record_partitioned.record_id = DT.record ^F
                                                                      ^

[2022-01-04 11:57:23+0000]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_fetcher.py", line 1428, in worker_sentiment
    (record_query, sentiment_query))
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "^F"
LINE 1: ...timent) AS DT WHERE record_partitioned.record_id = DT.recoP^F
                                                                      ^
```

Any idea?!

**UPDATE**

The version of psycopg2 is `2.7.7`.

The version on Postgres is `PostgreSQL 11.14 (Debian 11.14-0+deb10u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit`

And output of `mogrify` function for one of exceptions is:

```
[2022-01-08 07:02:08+0000] UPDATE record_partitioned SET sentiment = DT.sentiment FROM 
                    (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1382909136,1382909138,1382909139,1382909140,1382909142,1382909144,1382909146,1382909150,1382909152,1382909154,1382909156,1382909158,1382909161,1382909162,1382909164,1382909165,1382909166,1382909167,1382909169,1382909171,1382909173,1382909175,1382909177,1382909179,1382909180,1382909181,1382909183,1382909184,1382909185,1382909187,1382909189,1382909191,1382909193,1382909195,1382909197,1382909198,1382909199,1382909200,1382909201,1382909202,1382909203,1382909204,1382909206,1382909208,1382909210,1382909213,1382909214,1382909216,1382909218,1382909220,1382909222,1382909224,1382909225,1382909226,1382909228,1382909230,1382909232,1382909234,1382909236,1382909237,1382909239,1382909241,1382909243,1382909245,1382909246,1382909247,1382909249,1382909251,1382909252,1382909253,1382909254,1382909255,1382909257,1382909259,1382909260,1382909262,1382909264,1382909266,1382909267,1382909269,1382909272,1382909273,1382909275,1382909277,1382909279,1382909281,1382909282,1382909284,1382909286,1382909287,1382909289,1382909291,1382909293,1382909295,1382909297,1382909301,1382909302,1382909304,1382909306,1382909308]) AS record_id,UNNEST(ARRAY[1, -1, -1,0,1,0, -1, -1,0, -1, -1, -1,1, -1,1, -1,1, -1, -1,1, -1, -1, -1,1,1,0, -1, -1, -1,0, -1, -1,1,0, -1, -1,0,1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,0,0, -1, -1, -1, -1,1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,0,1, -1, -1, -1,0, -1,1, -1, -1, -1, -1,0, -1, -1, -1,0, -1, -1,1, -1,1,0, -1,0,0, -1,0, -1,0,0, -1,0,0,1, -1, -1,0,1,0, -1,1, -1, -1, -1]) AS sentiment) AS DT 
                    WHERE record_partitioned.record_id = DT.record_id
```

Comment: Looks to me whatever client you are using is inserting some character.  I would try using a triple quoted string for the query.

Comment: thanks for answer. I will try 3 quoted, the weird thing is that happen rarely, and most of times it is OK.  I tried to use ```mogrify``` function to watch what exactly query cause exception. the output query was normal, I could even execute it!

Comment: Add the new code and the mogrify output to your question. Also what client are you running the code in? What version of `psycopg2`? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: I'm going to say it is due to this; 'I use python 2.7...'. Python 2.7 is past EOL and the newest version of `psycopg2` does not  support it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your answer.  If it is important I get this warning when I run my code ```.../psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.```

Comment: I'm not sure about client, but it seems psycopg2 is a wrapper for the ```libpq``` isn't it?. for command line I use ```psql```

Comment: I'd consider installing via `pip install psycopg2==2.7.7` rather than `pip install psycopg2-binary`, to see if building from source fixes the issue (perhaps your psycopg2 install has got out of sync with the server install somehow?).

Comment: `psycopg2` is running in something, is that a module or the Python shell, ipython, PyCharm, etc? Are you actually running in Python 2.7 or is the 2.7 a reference to the `pscyopg2` version?

Comment: Its just a simple python file that I run it with ```nice -n 19 python data_fetcher.py``` in an virtual environment include python 2.7.16 and psycopg2 2.7.7

Comment: Problem solved with upgrading ```psycopg2``` to ```2.8.6```.